# Extract folder name right before filename from filepath

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

how can I extract the folder name of a filepath sitting right before the filename?

Example:

```
declare @a varchar(200)
set @a = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'
select right(@a, charindex('/', reverse(@a)) - 1)
```

this returns filename.txt - In another column I now want to get the "category1" folder name.
If the path changes to:
 `set @b = '/path/to/another/folder/category2/filename.txt'`
it should extract **category2**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example code, you can extract the last folder name with the following snippet

```
declare @a varchar(200), @b varchar(200), @c varchar(200)
set @a = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'
set @b = right(@a, charindex('/', reverse(@a)) - 1)
set @c = replace(@a, '/' + @b, '')
select right(@c, charindex('/', reverse(@c)) - 1), @b
```

in one select statement (except @a)

```
declare @a VARCHAR(200)
set @a = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'

select right(replace(@a, '/' + right(@a, charindex('/', reverse(@a)) - 1), ''), charindex('/', reverse(replace(@a, '/' + right(@a, charindex('/', reverse(@a)) - 1), ''))) - 1) as folder, right(@a, charindex('/', reverse(@a)) - 1) as filename
```

Comment: replace last statement with
select right(@c, charindex('/', reverse(@c)) - 1)as 'folder Name',
@b as 'File Name'

Comment: Is this possible without the variables? So that I can use it in one select stmt like: expression1 AS folderName and expression2 as fileName

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method below:

```
declare @a varchar(200)
set @a = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'


select reverse(
            SUBSTRING(reverse(@a),
                charindex('/', reverse(@a)) + 1 ,
                CHARINDEX('/',reverse(@a),charindex('/', reverse(@a))+ 1) - charindex('/', reverse(@a)) -1)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out....shortest solution...

declare @a varchar(200)
set @a = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'

declare @a varchar(200)
set @a = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'

select replace(right(SUBSTRING(@a,0,(LEN(@a)- CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@a),0)+1)),charindex('/',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@a,0,(LEN(@a)- CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@a),0)+1))),0)),'/','')

Answer (score 0):

Another method to extract the separate folder location and the file name strings.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(200) = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'

SELECT LEFT(@a, LEN(@a)- LEN(RIGHT(@a,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@a))-1))) Folder,
   RIGHT(@a,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@a))-1) FileName
```

Note: If your file path string has back slashes instead of forward ones just change the slashes in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Folder VARCHAR(100)

SET @Folder = '/path/to/category1/filename.txt'

SELECT
    REPLACE(@Folder,
    (SELECT
        TOP 1 value
    FROM
        (SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [Row],
            value
        FROM
            STRING_SPLIT(@Folder, '/')) AS TblTemp
        ORDER BY [Row] DESC) , '' )
```